# multiple TCPclients over single network stream

Tags: c#, imap, tcpclient

my question is how can i connect multiple tcp clients with a single imap server . it's for the testing purpose for my program.
as i can connects them by making a single new function for every client but cant figure out for multiple clients.
thanks in advance.

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

```
    public static TcpClient _imapClient1= new TcpClient("server addres",143);
    public static TcpClient _imapClient2 = new TcpClient(server addres, 143);

    public static NetworkStream _imapNs1;
    public static NetworkStream _imapNs2;
    public static StreamWriter _imapSw1;
    public static StreamWriter _imapSw2;
    public static StreamReader _imapSr1;
    public static StreamReader _imapSr2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        Thread thread1 = new Thread(startThread1);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(startThread2);

        thread2.Start();
        thread1.Start();
    }


    public static void startThread1()
    {


        connectToIMAP1(_imapClient1);

        LoginUser1("user1", "12345");


        Thread.Yield();
    }

    public static void startThread2()
    {


        connectToIMAP2(_imapClient2);
        LoginUser2("user2", "12345");

        Thread.Yield();
    }




    public static void connectToIMAP1(TcpClient _imapClient)

    {
        try
        {

            _imapNs1 = _imapClient.GetStream();
            _imapSw1 = new StreamWriter(_imapNs1);
            _imapSr1 = new StreamReader(_imapNs1);
            Response1(_imapClient1);

            //  MessageBox.Show("*** Connected ***");
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

     public static void connectToIMAP2(TcpClient _imapClient)

    {
        try
        {

            _imapNs2 = _imapClient.GetStream();
            _imapSw2 = new StreamWriter(_imapNs2);
            _imapSr2 = new StreamReader(_imapNs2);
            Response2(_imapClient2);

            //  MessageBox.Show("*** Connected ***");
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }




    public static string Response1(TcpClient _imapClient)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[_imapClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int ret = _imapNs1.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        // string lines = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).ToString());
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).TrimEnd();



    }

    public static string Response2(TcpClient _imapClient)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[_imapClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int ret = _imapNs2.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        // string lines = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).ToString());
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).TrimEnd();



    }



    public static void LoginUser1(string username, string password)
    {
        _imapSw1.WriteLine("$ LOGIN " + username + " " + password);
        _imapSw1.Flush();
        Response1(_imapClient1);

    }


    public static void LoginUser2(string username, string password)
    {
        _imapSw2.WriteLine("$ LOGIN " + username + " " + password);
        _imapSw2.Flush();
        Response2(_imapClient2);

  }
```

}

Comment: Make a class, in it have the imap connection, the login, the password, the server the port.  then you can have 1 function per thing you need to do to any imap client, and depending on which instance it applies to, is the one it works with..

Comment: You can't have two connections with the same 3 properties : Source IP address, Destination IP addtress, port number.  I recommend for testing is to have server open 3 connections with different port numbers and do same at client.  The only other choice is to have 3 ethernet cards on client so your client can have three different source IP addresses.

Comment: This is not related to C++.

Comment: @jdweng Sure you can, as long as the source port is different as well, these are unique connections.  Email clients can, and do, make multiple IMAP connections to the same server from the same source IP, to monitor multiple folders at once.

Comment: Max : How can the source port be different from the destination port?  The IMAP connection is probably using Port Forwarding which moves connection to a different port number.  A TCP client will not use port forwarding unless you add the code.  IMAP uses SSL which required port forwarding.

Comment: @jdweng I don't know what you're talking about.  A TCP connection is defined by four objects: source up, source port, destination up, destination port.  The source port is generally randomly assigned by the OS from the "high" range (above 10000), unless you use bind() to specifically request a certain source port.  This is generally invisible to the client app.  TLS does not change this.  The NAT if it exists, will map each unique connection to a unique port on it as well.

Comment: I was a network engineer for 5 years and the source and destination IP address are always the same for TCP.  I'm an expert on TCP.  Read most of the IEEE specifications (RFCs).